# Why are there multiple api endpoints for azure oauth?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

What is the difference between:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directory ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Using common (the first endpoint) seems to work fine for generating my tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register an application in Azure AD, you are asked to choose the account types that can use the application.

[image]

The endpoints essentially corresponds to these.

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`: You can use `common` endpoint to authenticate/authorize any account (Personal Microsoft Account or Work/School Account).
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`: When you use `organizations`  endpoint, only Work/School Account can be authenticated. Personal Microsoft Accounts cannot be authenticated/authorized.
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directory ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`: When you specify the directory id (also known as Tenant Id) in the endpoint, only Work/School Accounts in that tenant can be authenticated/authorized. Personal Microsoft Accounts and Work/School Accounts in other tenants cannot be authenticated/authorized unless they are added to the tenant as guest users.